# springframework boot test context does not exist

Tags: java, spring, pom.xml

I am using dependencias as below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the error code it shows is:
**java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist**

I've looked over other people topics with this problem but nothing seemed to fix it.

I've also had the error: junit jupiter api not found, but I fixed it by Configuring Project Structure of Jupiter from "Test" to "Compile".

Comment: Remove the `javaee-web-api` dependency, ditch the `spring-tx` and `hiberbate-core` and add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead. Ditch the `hibernate-valiator` dependency as well and add `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. The fact that you "fixed"  something clearly shows you are using test classes outside the scope of tests and in your main project structure.